# Удобная библиотека для создания запросов с cookie

Tags: c#, cookie, библиотеки, request, httpwebrequest

Делаю на основе стандартного HttpWebRequest вход на сайт через куки, т.е. делаю несколько запросов, используя куки, полученные в предыдущих.

Поскольку куки в HttpWebRequest сделаны очень криво (нет единого объекта для request и response куков), код работает через раз.

Есть ли удобные современные C# библиотеки для создания запросов с поддержкой прокси и нормальным куки менеджментом?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на [HttpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2).
Единственная проблема с Socks прокси, но она решается путём использования сторонних библиотек [ПРИМЕР](https://github.com/MihaZupan/HttpToSocks5Proxy)

Answer (score 0):

Советую использовать любую REST библиотеку для шарпа.

Родные инструменты .NET слишком низкоуровневые, хотя по-факту ко всем им можно прикрутить использование кук. Почему низкоуровневость это плохо? Код сложнее и его нужно писать больше.

Подойдет любая библиотека найденная по словам "C# rest nuget" в гугле. Тот же Rest.Net. Или же в поиске в NuGet Manager ищи по "Rest"